# Why are both servers behind my load balancer responding to every HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a Digital Ocean load balancer. Behind the load balancer are two servers. Both servers use an nginx reverse proxy which forwards traffic to a node script.

Everything is working fine, however I have noticed some weirdness.

Let's say a POST gets sent. The load balancer sends the POST to server1. Server1 acknowledges (POST) and replies. However server2 acknowledges (OPTIONS).

I don't understand how server2 is even aware of the POST request to server1.

Why is server2 replying with OPTIONS every time server1 replies to the POST request?

Surely server2 should not be aware of what server1 is doing?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how CORS preflight requests works, look at your browser, you should see two requests, one OPTIONS and one POST.

The first OPTIONS request is here to check if your client is allowed to access your API, the second POST is your API call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why is server1 replying to the POST, and server2 replying to the OPTIONS? Is this just each server sharing the request between them? Or does it suggest something odd is happening?

Comment: Seems like load balancing works fine, nothing odd here.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel.

Answer (score 2):

The load balancer seems to be working. It is splitting the request as POST and OPTIONS are two separate request. OPTIONS request are sent because of browser security and CORS. Don't think of that OPTIONS + POST request as the same request. They are separate and the server needs to respond to each of them so server2 doesn't know about the POST request, only the OPTIONS so the load balancer is doing its job correctly.

Comment: Thank you User9123.